# how to pass and access data to partial view in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm adding a new partial view in ruby on rails project and want to pass some additional data to the partial. I have code below for rendering a view . I understand this is the way to pass data (id in my case) to partial view. I'm not sure if this is the best way, as I'm new to rubyonrails. How do i access in my partial view file?

```
render "index" , :locals => {:id => params[:id]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass data to your view(s) using options on `render`, one of which is `locals`, or by setting instance variables which automatically propagate.

Normally what's done is something like this:

```
@id_param = params[:id]
```

Where within your view you can use `@id_param` wherever and whenever:

```
<%= @id_param %>
```

I've chosen `@id_param` for a name here instead of `@id` to give it a bit more context as `@id` on its own might prompt questions of "What ID?"

If you want to do the `locals` method, then:

```
render 'index', locals: { id: params[:id] }
```

Using the Ruby 1.9 hash notation for simplicity here, versus the outdated 1.8 style in your original example. This produces a local variable called `id` that can be used in that view, like:

```
<%= id %>
```

Comment: thanks . that answers my questions. as we are in the topic, if you don't mind, could you tell me, if there is any benefit of using the locals method. i simply followed a tutorial, but didn't realize it is a special method.

Comment: You don't normally use `locals` at the top-level when making a `render` call in the controller, but it can be useful when rendering partials *within* a view where you want to customize how that partial behaves without changing instance variables. Any change to instance variables in a view changes *every* partial after that point in rendering, while `local` impacts only that particular render call.